# how to sort a multiline textbox without using an array

Tags: c#, sorting, textbox

i just wrote a code that will sort the textbox but i want to know is there any other ways that does not require an intermediate array?!(just to improve performance)

here's the code i wrote:

```
        string[] textbox = new string[textBox1.Lines.Length];
        textbox = textBox1.Text.Split('\r');
        textBox1.Clear();
        Array.Sort(textbox);
        foreach(string text in textbox)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(text + "\r\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work directly with the Lines property (and this is already an array).

```
 textBox1.Lines = textBox1.Lines.OrderBy(l => l).ToArray();
```

(Note that in any case you have to rebuild the Lines array so it is not really possible to avoid an array, it is just materialized after the OrderBy in this code)

Comment: this was way more faster than what i wrote.

Comment: the appendtext takes too much time to perform the action

Answer (score 0):

Use `OrderBy`:

```
var s= textBox1.Text.Split('\r').OrderBy(c=>c);
textBox1.Clear();
foreach (string text in s)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(text + "\r\n");
}
```

You could also do this without `foreach` loop just by using [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var s = string.Join("\r\n", textBox1.Text.Split('\r').OrderBy(c => c));
textBox1.Clear();
textBox1.AppendText(s);
```